# Wordpress admin-ajax.php returns php code instead of json

Tags: php, json, ajax, wordpress, nginx

**How do I make WordPress return JSON on Nginx?**

In my wordpress, Ajax calls return `<?php JSON` instead just plain `JSON`.
The site works just fine, except for admin-ajax calls.

**Regular call**
[image: SessionSniff]

**File upload call**
[image: FileUploadSniff]

**TechInfo:**

```
Wordpress 4.5
PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (fpm-fcgi)
nginx version: nginx/1.9.3 (Ubuntu)
```

**Headers sniff:**

```
Request URL:http://SERVER/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:IP:80
Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://SERVER
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 26 Apr 2016 06:44:17 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/1.9.3 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Robots-Tag:noindex
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:107
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:REDACTED ;)
Host:SERVER
Origin:http://SERVER
Referer:http://SERWER/wp-admin/media-new.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.86 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
data[wp-auth-check]:true
interval:60
_nonce:32b36eaa97
action:heartbeat
screen_id:media
has_focus:false
```

**NGINX**

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you have extre <?php tag there somewhere in your code check it properly.

Comment: the WP installation is brand new. I will try @Fiil 's answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this topic.
**The problem was NO COMMENTS in functions.php file**
After I added the following to `functions.php`, the problem disappeared.

```
<?php
/**
 * Twenty Fifteen functions and definitions
 *
 * Set up the theme and provides some helper functions, which are used in the
 * theme as custom template tags. Others are attached to action and filter
 * hooks in WordPress to change core functionality.
 *
 * When using a child theme you can override certain functions (those wrapped
 * in a function_exists() call) by defining them first in your child theme's
 * functions.php file. The child theme's functions.php file is included before
 * the parent theme's file, so the child theme functions would be used.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
 *
 * Functions that are not pluggable (not wrapped in function_exists()) are
 * instead attached to a filter or action hook.
 *
 * For more information on hooks, actions, and filters,
 * {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API}
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */
```

Comment: Yeah it's correct, but in general, this problem arises because you don't have an empty line after `<?php` tag

Answer (score 0):

Check if you wordpress files were not compromised. You probably have some modification made in core Wordpress files that adds "

Do fresh install of Wordpress files and check it it still exists.
All modification to wordpress should be done in theme folder or plugins.

I problem still occurs try to disable all plugins and turn on one by one. It is possible that one of plugins is messing up.

Comment: completel fresh install, I removed ALL plugins, still the same :(

Comment: It looks like you have something wrong with nginx configuration. How does raw response for non AJAX requests looks like?

Comment: Non ajax works perfectly. WP works, I can edit posts and display them.. it's just AJAX that returns `<?phpJSON`

Comment: Did you tried fresh install of Wordpress (new folder, new database, default theme, no plugins)? Does non-AJAX responses begins with <?php as well (view source) - it might be cleaned by browser but exist.

Comment: yes I did. I completely removed all files and uploaded new ones. Removed everything from plugins, attached a new table in DB (can't create new DB). still nothing. Checked file permissions, nginx "fixpath" settings, php versions, headers, file owners... I'm lost :(