# Wordpress ajax returns JSON with php opening tag

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating an ajax registration in wordpress. I process the data sent from JS to PHP then send back a response using the code below.

```
wp_send_json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'Please select a user type.' )));
```

But the JSON response I get always starts with a php opening tag.

```
<?php{"success":"false","message":"Please select a user type."}
```

Can't find what's causing this.

Here's my php code

```
<?php

if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    add_action( 'init', 'auth_init' );
}

function auth_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'user-auth-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/user-auth.js', array(), false, true );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_registration', 'ajax_registration');
}

add_action( 'buddyboss_after_header', 'registration_modal' );
function registration_modal() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !bp_is_register_page() ) {
        $bp = buddypress();

        if( empty( $bp->signup->step ) )
            $bp->signup->step='request-details';

        get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'registration-modal' );
    }
}

/**
 * Ajax Registration
 */
function ajax_registration(){

    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-register-nonce', 'security' );

    $info = array();

    $info[ 'user_nicename' ]    = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
    $info[ 'nickname' ]         = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
    $info[ 'display_name' ]     = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
    $info[ 'user_login' ]       = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
    $info[ 'user_pass' ]        = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'password' ] );
    $info[ 'user_email' ]       = sanitize_email( $_POST[ 'email' ] );

    // Checks if user type entered is valid
    if ( !$_POST[ 'user_type' ] ) {
        wp_send_json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'Please select a user type.' )));
    }
    elseif ( sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'user_type' ] ) === 'client' ) {
        $info[ 'role' ] = 'client';
    }
    elseif ( sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'user_type' ] ) === 'vendor' ) {
        $info[ 'role' ] = 'vendor';
    }
    else {
        wp_send_json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'Invalid user type selected.' )));
    }

    // Registers the user
    $user_register = wp_insert_user( $info );

    // Checks for errors returned
    if ( is_wp_error( $user_register ) ) {
        $error = $user_register->get_error_codes();

        if ( in_array( 'empty_user_login', $error ) ) {
            wp_send_json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( $user_register->get_error_message( 'empty_user_login' ) )));
        }
        elseif ( in_array( 'existing_user_login', $error ) ) {
            wp_send_json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'This username you entered is already registered.' )));
        }
        elseif ( in_array( 'existing_user_email', $error ) ) {
            wp_send_json(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'This email address you entered is already registered.' )));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Log in user
 * @param  string $username Username
 * @param  string $password Password
 * @return boolean           [description]
 */
function auth_user_login( $username, $password ) {
    $info = array();
    $info[ 'user_login' ]       = $username;
    $info[ 'user_password' ]    = $password;
    $info[ 'remember' ]         = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error( $user_signon ) ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        wp_set_current_user( $user_signon->ID );
        return true;
    }
}
```

user-auth.js

```
$(function () {

    $( '#signup_submit' ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var btn = $( this ).button( 'loading' );

        var data = {
            action: "ajax_registration",
            user_type: $( 'input[name=signup_user_type]:checked', '#signup_form' ).val(),
            username: $( '#signup_username' ).val(),
            password: $( '#signup_password' ).val(),
            email: $( '#signup_email' ).val(),
            security: $( '#registration-security' ).val()
        };

        $.post( ajaxurl, data, function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
            btn.button( 'reset' );
        } );

    });


});
```

Comment: you have a extra `<?php ` tag?

Comment: @madalinivascu, I don't have any extra `<?php` tag

Comment: are you 100% sure?

Comment: yes, I am 100% sure

Comment: Please share your full php code

Comment: @StanimirStoyanov, I've edited my post. thanks

Comment: @marccaps please add your `user-auth.js` code

Comment: @Firefog I've added the user-auth.js

Comment: add data type `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: @Firefog, still, no luck. I've already used the old jquery.ajax() method with dataType.

Comment: @marccaps could you please remove any extra spaces after <?php or where from start the message. If will solve your issue

Comment: Still doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @marccaps check my answer this may help you

Comment: Hello please check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36939507/6417957

Answer (score 0):

**1st Solution**

In your php code any where related to your registration form or form handler did you use  something like this ?

```
<?php function xxxxxx (){ ?>

<p>some text </p>

<?php } ?>
```

If yes then change it to like

```
<?php 
function xxxxxx (){ 
$vriable = '<p>some text </p>';
return $vriable
}
```

**2Nd Solution**

`wp_send_json()` handles all parts of returning content in an AJAX call. First off, it sets the content type of the returned content to application/json with the proper charset. Secondly, it automatically calls `wp_die()` after sending the JSON result, which is necessary in an AJAX call in WordPress.

You could consider using `wp_send_json_success()` for successful requests and `wp_send_json_error()` for erroneous requests, thereby adhering to the WordPress standards for handling AJAX requests. These functions set a `success` (boolean) and `data` (any type) key in an array and encode that entire array, thereby allowing you easily check in a structured way whether the request was successful or whether something went wrong.

I have edit your code a little bit

```
<?php
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {


    function auth_init() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'user-auth-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/user-auth.js', array(), false, true ); 
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'auth_init' );


    function registration_modal() {
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !bp_is_register_page() ) {
            $bp = buddypress();

            if( empty( $bp->signup->step ) )
                $bp->signup->step='request-details';

            get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'registration-modal' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'buddyboss_after_header', 'registration_modal' );

    /**
     * Ajax Registration
     */

    function ajax_registration(){

        check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-register-nonce', 'security' );
        $info = array();

        $info[ 'user_nicename' ]    = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
        $info[ 'nickname' ]         = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
        $info[ 'display_name' ]     = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
        $info[ 'user_login' ]       = sanitize_user( $_POST[ 'username' ] );
        $info[ 'user_pass' ]        = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'password' ] );
        $info[ 'user_email' ]       = sanitize_email( $_POST[ 'email' ] );

        // Checks if user type entered is valid
        if ( !$_POST[ 'user_type' ] ) {
            wp_send_json_error(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'Please select a user type.' )));
        }
        elseif ( sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'user_type' ] ) === 'client' ) {
            $info[ 'role' ] = 'client';
        }
        elseif ( sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'user_type' ] ) === 'vendor' ) {
            $info[ 'role' ] = 'vendor';
        }
        else {
            wp_send_json_error(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'Invalid user type selected.' )));
        }

        // Registers the user
        $user_register = wp_insert_user( $info );

        // Checks for errors returned
        if ( is_wp_error( $user_register ) ) {
            $error = $user_register->get_error_codes();

            if ( in_array( 'empty_user_login', $error ) ) {
                wp_send_json_error(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( $user_register->get_error_message( 'empty_user_login' ) )));
            }
            elseif ( in_array( 'existing_user_login', $error ) ) {
                wp_send_json_error(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'This username you entered is already registered.' )));
            }
            elseif ( in_array( 'existing_user_email', $error ) ) {
                wp_send_json_error(array('success' => 'false', 'message' => __( 'This email address you entered is already registered.' )));
            }
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_registration', 'ajax_registration');
    /**
     * Log in user
     * @param  string $username Username
     * @param  string $password Password
     * @return boolean           [description]
     */
    function auth_user_login( $username, $password ) {
        $info = array();
        $info[ 'user_login' ]       = $username;
        $info[ 'user_password' ]    = $password;
        $info[ 'remember' ]         = true;

        $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
        if ( is_wp_error( $user_signon ) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            wp_set_current_user( $user_signon->ID );
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still does not solve my issue. I've noticed that all the response even the wordpress auth check pass json with an opening php tag `<?php{"wp-auth-check":false,"server_time":1480418708}`

Comment: @is it in your local server ? or live server ? can you show me the link?

Comment: @marccaps I have added another possible solution please check

Comment: it's on my local server. I've applied both of your solutions but the issue still exists.

Comment: It's the buddypress plugin. Whenever I activate it, the `<?php` tag is prepended. Still don't know what caused this. I've already reported this on their support. Thanks for all your help, @Firefog!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this topic. The problem was NO COMMENTS in functions.php file After I added the following to functions.php, the problem disappeared.

check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36939507/6417957

```
 <?php
/**
 * Twenty Fifteen functions and definitions
 *
 * Set up the theme and provides some helper functions, which are used in the
 * theme as custom template tags. Others are attached to action and filter
 * hooks in WordPress to change core functionality.
 *
 * When using a child theme you can override certain functions (those wrapped
 * in a function_exists() call) by defining them first in your child theme's
 * functions.php file. The child theme's functions.php file is included before
 * the parent theme's file, so the child theme functions would be used.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
 *
 * Functions that are not pluggable (not wrapped in function_exists()) are
 * instead attached to a filter or action hook.
 *
 * For more information on hooks, actions, and filters,
 * {@link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API}
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fifteen
 * @since Twenty Fifteen 1.0
 */
```

Comment: Yeah it's correct, but in general, this problem arises because you don't have an empty line after `<?php` tag